# In C#, how do you output the contents of a Dictionary class?

Tags: c#, dictionary

In C#, how do you output the contents of a Dictionary class?

Once you have loaded a Dictionary class with keys and values, how do I cycle through them and output the individual values in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to output them you dont need a [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement) loop.
You can use LINQ [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx):

```
myDictionary.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key + " : " + x.Value));
```

Comment: @Gabe: ofcourse it is... But to differentiate it from a "normal" `foreach` loop I specifically wrote LINQ `ForEach`, which is a method...

Comment: Well, saying *you don't need a foreach loop* can be misunderstood. Some people think LINQ is pure magic and doesn't use up CPU time.

Comment: Hehe... Not my intention... Added links to clarify... :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example from http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Example Dictionary again
    Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"cat", 2},
        {"dog", 1},
        {"llama", 0},
        {"iguana", -1}
    };
    // Loop over pairs with foreach
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",
        pair.Key,
        pair.Value);
    }
    // Use var keyword to enumerate dictionary
    foreach (var pair in d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",
        pair.Key,
        pair.Value);
    }
    }
}
```

The last loop uses *var* to declare the KeyValuePair object. It's easier this way, since you don't have to worry about declaring the types used in the Dictionary, and produces the same result to the CLR.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in myDictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",
    pair.Key,
    pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var key in pair.Keys){
   Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", key, pair[key]);      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Dictionary<object, object> dummyDictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>
            {
                {"India","Delhi"},
                {"USA","WashingtonDC"},
                {"Bangaladesh","Dhaka"},
                {"Pakistan","Karachi"}
            };
```

**//Foreach loop construct**

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> kvp in dummyDictionary)
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key = {0}  Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
}
```

**//using Linq and Foreach Extension method**

```
var result =
             (from kvp in dummyDictionary
              select new
              {
                Key = kvp.Key
                ,
                 Value = kvp.Value
              });
result.ToList().ForEach(kvp => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key = {0}  Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean, saying *and output the individual values*? Are you expecting to see only unique values?

```
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"1","one"},
            {"2","two"},
            {"3","three"},
            {"4","one"}
        };

        foreach (var value in dict.Values.Distinct())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

That is, you may use `Distinct()` to get unique values, whereas  `dict.Values` is the `ValueColection` of the dictionary